# How To Insert to Server After Doing Something

Tags: react-native

What I am trying to do is when the page is loaded up, it will call the `this.getKey()` method and after it is called, it will call again the `this.InsertDataToServer` to populate the text fields. However, currently that is not working and all the text fields are blank since `this.InsertDataToServer` is never called. What is my problem in my code?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  StatusBar,
  Alert
} from 'react-native';
import { Card, Button, Header, Left, Body, Right, Title, Form, Label, Item, Input} from 'native-base';
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';

export default class Profile extends Component {
  componentWillMount(){
    this.getKey().then(()=>{
      this.InsertDataToServer
    });
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      mysessionUsername:null,
      username: '',
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      emailAddress: '',
      phoneNumber: '',
      Address: '',
      parseMe: null
    }
  }

  async getKey() {
    try {
      AsyncStorage.getItem('sessionUsername').then((value) => {
        this.setState({"mysessionUsername": value});
      })
      .then(res => {
        // Alert.alert(this.state.mysessionUsername);
      });
      //await this.setState({ lchMoteurRch: AsyncVal });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error retrieving data" + error);
    }
  }

  async saveKey(value) {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('sessionUsername', value);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error saving data" + error);
    }
  }

  InsertDataToServer = () =>{
    //const { TextUserName }  = this.state ;
    fetch('someLink.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: this.state.mysessionUsername,
      }) 
    })

    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      // Showing response message coming from server after inserting records.
      Alert.alert(responseJson);
      this.state.parseMe = responseJson;
      this.state.parseMe = this.state.parseMe.split(" ");
      this.setState({
        "username": this.state.parseMe[0],
        "firstName": this.state.parseMe[1],
        "lastName": this.state.parseMe[2],
        "emailAddress": this.state.parseMe[3],
        "phoneNumber": this.state.parseMe[4],
        "Address": this.state.parseMe[5]
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
      <Header style={styles.header}>
        <Left>
          <Title>Account</Title>
        </Left>
        <Right>
         </Right>
      </Header>

      <StatusBar
        backgroundColor='#000000'
      />

      <Card>
      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Username: {this.state.username}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>First Name: {this.state.firstName}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Last Name: {this.state.lastName}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Email Address: {this.state.emailAddress}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Phone Number: {this.state.phoneNumber}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Address: {this.state.Address}</Text>
      </Card>

      <Button
        full
        rounded
        success
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('LoginForm')}
        >
        <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>LOG OUT</Text>

      </Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  textStyle: {
    fontSize: 25,
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginTop: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
  button: {
    marginTop: 20,
    marginLeft: 40,
    marginRight: 40
  },
  header: {
    backgroundColor: '#00b3b3',
    color: 'white'
  }
};
```

Comment: can you try to add brackets to function call? from `this.InsertDataToServer` to this `this.InsertDataToServer()`

Comment: That did not work